# Python unicode displayed in editor and stored in memory

Tags: python, unicode

I am python new learner.
Here is a question confused me. 
My intention is to store a Chinese character in a variable.
I tried two different ways:
Method 1:

```
>>> x = u'\u6ce8'
>>> print x
注
```

Method 2:

```
>>> y = u'注'
>>> y
u'\xd7\xa2'
>>> print y
×¢
```

If i use method 2, in the python interpreter or a text editor, the character is displayed as I typed in.

But actually in the memory, this unicode character is converted into two bytes.
And the byte value is different from the real value for that character (in method 1)

Question:

1. In method 2, who does this conversion from the chinese character I typed in to those two bytes? OS, python interpreter?
2. Why the conversion seems wrong? (should be 6ce8 not d7a2)
3. Why if I save the script to a .py file and open it again, I can
   see the correct character as I typed in?
4. What is your solution for method 2 that I can print the right character?

   Thanks in advance!

Comment: "in the python interpreter or a text editor" The interpreter runs in a shell, that shell has an encoding associated with it, it is either Unicode encoding or it is something else. Your editor displays (and stores) in an encoding; it is Unicode or not. The problem is with your terminal or editor, which are probably using one of dozens of encodings that are not Unicode. Fix that, and you'll find that Python is working fine.

Comment: @msw: this is perfectly on topic here. Python is a commonly used programming tool, debugging issues with I/O in the interactive interpreter is a common topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apparently pasted [*GBK* data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK):

```
>>> u'\u6ce8'.encode('gbk')
'\xd7\xa2'
```

GBK uses multiple bytes to encode codepoints; how many depends on the exact codepoint, but it'll either be one or two bytes.

However, your console or terminal is telling Python it is configured to handle Latin-1 or another 8-bit codec, so Python decoded the bytes straight to Unicode:

```
>>> '\xd7\xa2'.decode('latin1')
u'\xd7\xa2'
```

You can see what codec Python thinks needs to be used by printing the `sys.stdin.encoding` attribute; my terminal is configured for UTF-8:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'UTF-8'
```

This is ultimately determined from your system locale configuration. Python queries this with the [`locale.getpreferredencoding()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding). On POSIX systems (Linux, OS X) you can check your locale with the `locale` command.